# Updating ca certificate for pgadmin

Tags: certificate, pgadmin

I have enabled Oauth2 for pgadmin(4.6.20). I need to use the ca certificate signed by my company.

I have created a cacert.pem file under /pgadmin4 as the config.py file mentioned

```
CA_FILE = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)),          
                   "cacert.pem")
```

Still I am getting the error
(Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))","info":"","result":null,"data":null}

In config_distro.py the location of CA_FILE = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

I have even updated the contents of this file but still getting the same error.

There are no other config files like config_local.py and config_system.py

What can I do to fix the above error

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are on Ubuntu or Debian, you may miss the `sudo update-ca-certificates` after you changed the file, please refer to the readme file on how to update the certificate:
/usr/share/doc/ca-certificates/README.Debian